# Facebook Profile Picture not showing in Chrome

Tags: facebook-graph-api, google-chrome

I am having issue with loading Facebook Profile Images in my application. I get list of my friends fromt the graph API and then display the relevant Friend Info and their public profile images

My HTML is as below.

```
<div id = "profile_picture" style="float:left; width:100px;height: 100px" >
                <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/{{providerUserId}}/picture?width=100&height=100"/>
            </div>
            <div id="user_basic_info" style="float:left;margin-left:14px;">
                <div id="name" style="font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;margin-bottom:6px;">{{name}}</div>
                <div id="email" style="margin-bottom:6px;width:400px;">{{email}}</div>
                <div id="address"></div>
            </div>
```

The {{}} are Mustache templates which get populated via the model.
For some reason the images don't load up in Chrome; but work fine in Chrome Canary, Firefox, Safari.

It doesn't make a difference if I pass in hardcoded userId also.

Any guidance??

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/{{facebookProfileId}}/picture?width=100&height=100"

Comment: @CBroe are you asking for example or jsfiddle of the issue I am having?

Comment: Yes, a live example where Chrome refuses to load the image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check to see if you have any chrome plugins causing the issue by opening the url in incognito mode, that is assuming you have all the extensions disabled in that mode.

I noticed that the *disconnect* extension hid the images as you described.

Comment: Thanks that was the issue : )

Comment: Thanks! I had the same problem and it was the Disconnect extension that was blocking the images :)